# Azure WebApp Deployment throws error " Exit code 3 returned from process: file name '...\node\bin\node.exe', arguments ..\azurermwebappdeployment.js"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

**Azure web App(Angular) Deployment pipeline(CD) throws error. Check below Log**

```
2020-07-31T11:58:31.3433524Z ##[section]Starting: Azure App Service Deploy: WMWebUIDev
2020-07-31T11:58:31.3656726Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-31T11:58:31.3657151Z Task         : Azure App Service deploy
2020-07-31T11:58:31.3657598Z Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
2020-07-31T11:58:31.3657997Z Version      : 4.171.0
2020-07-31T11:58:31.3658240Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-07-31T11:58:31.3658568Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
2020-07-31T11:58:31.3658956Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-31T11:58:32.2076490Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'WMWebUIDev'
2020-07-31T12:00:08.4136171Z FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2020-07-31T12:00:08.9248151Z ##[error]Exit code 3 returned from process: file name 'C:\agents\2.172.2\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments '"D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.171.0\azurermwebappdeployment.js"'.
2020-07-31T12:00:08.9276443Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure App Service Deploy: WMWebUIDev
```

**My CD Tasks**
[image]

Comment: Please check this github issue and try apply proposed workarounds: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4734

Comment: This is known issue which results from large size of the contents in the zip file, can the workarounds from Krzysztof's link help to resolve your issue?

Comment: I have check answer suggested by you Krzysztof's,but it doesn't work. any idea?